# Call plugin when Maven profil is set

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, pom.xml

I have a Maven project and I have two profiles (Dev and integraiton). I use integration-profile to call two plugins, WAR and EAR maven plugin.

My question : how can I use the plugin in the pom.xml dependencies when integration-profile is set in the Maven goal (I don't Like to have a plugins call in the profile)?

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>integration-profile</id>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/jboss-web.xml</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <packagingExcludes>conf/jboss-roles-mapping.conf</packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        </build>
    </profile>
```

Comment: This will not call the plugins cause plugins are bound to the life cycle. This in result means you can't call two plugins within one pom you need to have at least to pom file one with packaging `ear`(maven-ear-plugin` and one with packaging `war` for maven-war-plugin. Can you describe more in detail what you like to achieve?

Comment: WAR and EAR because i must create the deployed project File is EAR contains war file for the web project and 10 jars for a EJB modules

Comment: Unfortunately you didn't answer my question to clear more up what you are trying to achieve.